# Print a tic-tac-toe board

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell and as an exercise, I am building a simple tic-tac-toe program. I start with

```
import Data.Vector

data Cell = Empty | X | O
type Board = Vector Cell
```

and then, to render the board:

```
render :: Board -> IO ()
render b = do
    renderSep
    renderRow 0 b
    renderSep
    renderRow 1 b
    renderSep
    renderRow 2 b
    renderSep
  where
    renderSep :: IO ()
    renderSep = putStrLn "+---+---+---+"
    renderRow :: Int -> Board -> IO ()
    renderRow r b = do
        putStr "| " >> putStr (cellRepr $ getCell r 0 b)
        putStr " | " >> putStr (cellRepr $ getCell r 1 b)
        putStr " | " >> putStr (cellRepr $ getCell r 2 b)
        putStrLn " |"
```

How could I abstract my implementation so that there's less repetition? Especially in the main body of the `render` function. I thought of using `sequence` together with the list `fmap (\x -> renderRow x b >> renderSep) [0, 1, 2]`. However, in this case I get a value of type `IO [()]` and not `IO ()`.

Comment: Have you tried writing functions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what you mean. I wrote functions, yes.

Comment: To avoid the repetition.

Comment: I don't know haskell, but if you can write loops in the language that should take care of some of the code repetition.

Comment: A possible improvement is to use [`forM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_) – notice the underscore, which is a convention and means that we discard the results. Using this function you can replace the repetitive part with `forM_ [0..2] $ \i -> renderRow i b >> renderSep`.

Comment: You can certainly use `sequence_` to get `IO ()` back. Or you can follow `sequence` by a `>> return ()`

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way to address the problem is by building the board first then printing it:

```
empty_row :: String
empty_row = "+---+---+---+"

board_repr :: type of b -> String
board_repr b = empty_row + concat ( map (\x -> (build_row x b) + empty_row ) [0, 1, 2] )

main = print (board_repr b)
```

Take this as pseudo-code pointing in an interesting direction by separating the concerns of building a representation and printing it.